# php url with comma changes into ASCII code

Tags: php, http, url

I have a url, it contains a comma , 
I use this url to call some remote system, the comma changes into 2C (ASCII code)
 which cause a problem to me!
How can I prevent this?

Comment: That's correct behavior, non-alphanumeric characters get replaced with `%` followed by the code; it's called _URL encoding_ or _Percent-encoding_. The server should decode it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing Wrong in this Behave. But for the case you want to Interpret this URL in some way, where you get the Encoded String back:
Try to Identify the Pattern where the Comma appears.
Example: variable=1&variable2=hello,someotherstuff
You could search here for someotherstuff if this is a variable and be sure, the %2C before is your Comma. If it changes, you could also ask for variable2=(randomstring). After that you get your Comma.

If you manage This, you can simply Divide the Code at that Point. All this can be done with the Function preg_match which uses Regular Expression for searching Patterns, and results in an Array of elements, found.

Regular Expression depends strongly on you String, since you dont give us the String, you have to figure out it on your own at this point. *caugh* RegExp is well explained on StackOverflow *caugh*